# Codeigniter Email Class is not working on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Codeigniter Email Class is not working on localhost

Errors

1. Message: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
2. Message: fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto
3. Message: fsockopen():unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Unknown error)

---

```
public function index()
{
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'fahadahmedkhan7223@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '********', 
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('fahadahmedkhan7223@gmail.com');
    $this->email->to('fahadahmedkhan7223@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Test');
    $this->email->message("This is test of codeigniter email class.");

    if($this->email->send())
    {
        echo 'Email sent.';
    }
    else
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }

}
```

Comment: Help me. i try every thing, but it still not working. :(

Comment: Did you set up the sendmail config on localhost you might need to configure the local host send mail https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TO7MfDcM-Ho

Comment: Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

Comment: '$config = Array(
         'protocol' => 'smtp',
         'smtp_host' => 'smtp.googlemail.com',
         'smtp_port' => 465,
         'smtp_user' => 'waqardeveloper4@gmail.com',
         'smtp_pass' => '********',
      'mailtype' => 'html'
   );
   
  
      
   $this->load->library('email', $config);
   $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");'

Comment: Still not working :(